# How Order Grid Filter in magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, filter

How can i **filter** the sale order grid by any **preference** , **observer** or **plugin** . How **override** sales order grid.

Can any one help me . I just want to apply condition just like addFeildToFilter and i pass custom_attribute with value and then just selected order record shown in grid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fortunately** am giving the answer of my own question. i spend 3 Days on this question i don't want to spend time any other **developer** .

I override the function which return the array or Collection that display the orders on Sales->Order page on admin site.

make di.xml file in "app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml"

and paste the code given below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" type="VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>
</config>
```

Now make the DataProvider.php File in such a way :
"VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider.php"

Paste the code given below.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface;

    class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
    {
        /**
         * Data Provider name
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * Data Provider Primary Identifier name
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $primaryFieldName;

        /**
         * Data Provider Request Parameter Identifier name
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $requestFieldName;

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        protected $meta = [];

        /**
         * Provider configuration data
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $data = [];

        /**
         * @var ReportingInterface
         */
        protected $reporting;

        /**
         * @var FilterBuilder
         */
        protected $filterBuilder;

        /**
         * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
         */
        protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

        /**
         * @var RequestInterface
         */
        protected $request;

        /**
         * @var SearchCriteria
         */
        protected $searchCriteria;
        protected $seller_order_arr;
        /**
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $primaryFieldName
         * @param string $requestFieldName
         * @param ReportingInterface $reporting
         * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
         * @param RequestInterface $request
         * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
         * @param array $meta
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            ReportingInterface $reporting,
            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            RequestInterface $request,
            FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
            array $meta = [],
            array $data = []
        )
        {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
            $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
            $this->reporting = $reporting;
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
            $this->meta = $meta;
            $this->data = $data;
            $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
        }
        protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
        {
            $arrItems = [];

            $arrItems['items'] = [];
            foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
                $itemData = [];
                foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
                }
                $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
                $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
        }
                    return $arrItems;
        }
            public function getSearchCriteria()
            {
                if (!$this->searchCriteria) {
                    $this->searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
                    $this->searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->name);
                }
                return $this->searchCriteria;
            }

            /**
             * Get data
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public
            function getData()
            {
                return $this->searchResultToOutput($this->getSearchResult());
            }

            /**
             * Get config data
             *
             * @return array
             */


            /**
             * Set data
             *
             * @param mixed $config
             * @return void
             */

            /**
             * Returns Search result
             *
             * @return SearchResultInterface
             */

              public function getSearchResult()
            {
                return $this->reporting->search($this->getSearchCriteria());
            }

    }
```

In the above code **$arrItems['items']** return the **array** that contains all **order collection**
You can Filter easily.

In my **case** i save the **custom_arribute** in **sales_order_grid** table and i want to filter rows or collection on the behalf on this **custom_attribute**

This my **Code** is **100%** Perfect.
Try this and save you important Time.

Befor run code should be compile `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: how will show grid in front end

Comment: Filter , Edit or Customize the  **$arrItems['items']** array and return it will be automatically set in grid in your frond end admin page.

Comment: $arrItems['items'] 

Can you show the example items for this plzz

Comment: i don't understand what you want to see ? i think you say show what i am filter or customize order grid ?

Comment: $arrItems['items']  here  which items  i can use 


expample 

Order id, Order status

Comment: Yes you can use .

Comment: is really work for front end and
how to find id for custom module

Comment: `$getCustomeId=[];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $getcustomer_id){
            $getCustomeId[]=$getcustomer_id['customer_id'];
        }
var_dump($getCustomeId);die('die');`

Paste this code where foreachloop end in **searchResultToOutput** function. then you can get all customer ids which own order.

You will get result like 
"array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) "1" } die"

Comment: i have another doubt how i will add to that specific page
if orders page in my account front end 

where the filters will show

Comment: carefully read my answer again i **explained** above in **answer** 

appreciate it  for help to others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90133/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-prabhakaran7).